# how to get moscow time with javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
new Date().toISOString()
```

This is giving me local date and time.
Is there any way to get moscow time ?

```
let options = {
    timeZone: "Europe/Moscow",
    year: "numeric",
    month: "numeric",
    day: "numeric",
    hour: "numeric",
    minute: "numeric",
    second: "numeric",
  },
  formatter = new Intl.DateTimeFormat([], options);
  let = date_ = new Date(Date.now())
  formatter.format(date_)
```

This works but, It is giving me different format for different timezone so it is breaking .

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript does not have native time zone support.

See JavaScript libraries like `Luxon` and `Moment` that add support for this.

To do it without a library, you'd need to use `(new Date()).getTimezoneOffset();` and convert that into how long to add or subtract from `Date.now()` for Moscow time.

Edit:

It seems modern browsers support this with:

```js
new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "Europe/Moscow"})
```